# How can I generate pkg-config files for my package?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Catkin package that generates several binaries and libraries, but unlike some other packages, pkg-config can't find them.

ROS seems to have set the path to both my Kinetic installation, as well as my workspace.

```
echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH 
somelocation/workspace/devel/lib/pkgconfig:somelocation/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/pkgconfig
```

When I ask  `pkg-config --list-all` about it, it does know about all of the ROS libraries, and also about things I installed in my own workspace, like `joy` and `uuid`. But it does not find the libraries I wrote myself.

I went over to the `CMakeLists.txt` of `joy` to see if I could find anything obvious that has to be done to generate the correct files, but can't see anything. There is no `.pc` file in the repo either. I also tried to google around, but all results are about using external packages inside ROS, not about using ROS package outside it.

Currently I'm just doing this, but that apparently does not get you any `pkg-config` files.
Full source: https://github.com/RoboTeamTwente/roboteam_tactics/blob/libskill/CMakeLists.txt

```
  add_library(Skill
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:treegen>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:tactics>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:utils>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:skills>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:conditions>
        )
  add_dependencies(Skill 
        ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
        ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
        )
```

When I run this, there is no output

```
$ pkg-config --list-all | grep -i skill
```

So what is the correct way to tell `pkg-config` about my library, just like `joy` and `uuid`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298197/how-can-i-generate-pkg-config-files-for-my-package?/) by [pepijndevos](https://answers.ros.org/users/35881/pepijndevos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2018-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
This should be done automatically for your package, but it will depend on you properly setting up (and ordering) your `CMakeLists.txt`. Please add that to your question so we can take a look.

**Comment by [pepijndevos](https://answers.ros.org/users/35881/pepijndevos/) on 2018-07-23**:
I've added a link to the source code: https://github.com/RoboTeamTwente/roboteam_tactics/blob/libskill/CMakeLists.txt I'm trying to link the Skill library that I added.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
That's quite a long `CMakeLists.txt`. I don't have time to check it all now, so I'll point you to [wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt). The ordering and contents of statements on that page should give you some things to check.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
Suggestion: try to create an MWE and see if that works with `pkg-config` (it should). Then do a diff (could be a mental one) between your MWE and your `roboteam_tactics` package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
Btw: [this](https://github.com/RoboTeamTwente/roboteam_tactics/blob/5ee184a110a02fedb58eebd3ed8ae5ad7d82029d/package.xml#L69) is no longer used by anything. It's something that the `rosbuild` system relied upon. Unless you have some custom tools that use it, it can probably be removed.

**Comment by [pepijndevos](https://answers.ros.org/users/35881/pepijndevos/) on 2018-07-23**:
Ah! Catkin makes a `pkg-config` entry for the whole `roboteam_tactics`, rather than any individual libraries I define. If I add `Skill` to `catkin_package()`, I can do `pkg-config --libs roboteam_tactics -Lsomewhere/lib -lroboteam_tactics_analysis -lSkill`. Is there a way to have skill on its own?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
The pkg config file is generated for the entire CMake project, in this case for your ROS package. I don't believe it's possible to generate a config file for each separate target, no.

**Comment by [pepijndevos](https://answers.ros.org/users/35881/pepijndevos/) on 2018-07-23**:
Ok. Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
I just noted [this commit](https://github.com/RoboTeamTwente/roboteam_tactics/commit/aa28910b8571180797cbfc6144275ccf8c1217a1). Note that in order for *any* targets to show up in your pkg config file (and be usable by other ROS pkgs) you *must* export them in the `LIBRARIES` section of your ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-23**:
.. `catkin_package(..)` call. That is not optional, and all of the examples that you mention (ie: `joy` and `uuid`) do this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(I'm going to post this as an answer, but it's really more a summary of the discussion in the comments)

What you're asking for is not possible afaik: Catkin will only generate a *single* pkg config file for a ROS package. It's not possible to have it generate multiple files (for separate targets fi).

It's actually the `catkin_package(..)` call that (eventually) generates the config file and the config file generated will contain information on all libraries added to the `LIBRARIES` argument of the `catkin_package(..)` call (and conversely: if you don't list a library there, it will not be mentioned in the pkg config file).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1